# waypoints sticky not initializing

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

OK, I'm  sure this is a simple problem, but I'm pulling my hair out.

I'm trying to make the element `.subheads_wrapper` sticky on my page.

I've put the latest waypoints files under Inetpub\wwwroot\includes\waypoints-master.

My page is in `Inetpub\wwwroot\mypage\index.php`

In the header, I've attached the proper files I think:

```
<script src="../includes/waypoints-master/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="../includes/waypoints-master/lib/shortcuts/sticky.min.js"></script>
```

css:

```
.stuck {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

jquery:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
     element: $('.subheads_wrapper')[0]
});
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Waypoint.Sticky is not a constructor

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recoding my page and just using the jquery waypoint function:

```
$('#screen2').waypoint(function(direction) {
           if (direction == 'down') {
            $('.freeze_column').css({'position':'fixed'});
            }
          if (direction == 'up') {
            $('.freeze_column').css({'position':'absolute'});

          }
      });
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you using the jQuery version of Waypoints? If so, where are you calling jQuery?

There are a few versions of the Waypoints plugin that are included when you download it: jQuery, Zepto, and "noframework".  If you are not using jQuery, then you want to make sure you're calling the "noframework" file:

```
noframework.waypoints.js
```

However, if you are using the jQuery version, as you stated in your question, I want to make sure you're calling jQuery and if so, where. This can help narrow down the issue.

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

The class constructor is not being found. It sounds like one or both js files are not loading properly.

When you instantiate a class by using the new operator it looks for a user defined or built-in object with the constructor name following the key word new.

Example:

```
var animal = new dog()
```

This would look through all currently loaded scripts for a dog constructor and will return the not a constructor error if none are found. Since we know the constructors for waypoints and stickys are found in the js files then it stands to reason they are not being loaded. Double check the paths to jquery.waypoints.min.js and sticky.min.js are correct. Also, verify through your browser console that they are actually being loaded and/or not disabled by something else.